# scrapy getting values from multiple sites

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to pass a value from a function.

i looked up the docs and just didn't understand it.
ref:

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['main_url'] = response.url
    request = scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                             callback=self.parse_page2)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    yield request

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['other_url'] = response.url
    yield item
```

here is a psudo code of what i want to achive:

```
import scrapy

class GotoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'goto'
    allowed_domains = ['first.com', 'second.com]
    start_urls = ['http://first.com/']

def parse(self, response):
    name = response.xpath(...)
    price = scrapy.Request(second.com, callback = self.parse_check)
    yield(name, price)


def parse_check(self, response):
    price = response.xpath(...)
    return price
```

Comment: do you want 1 item containing information from both sites? or one item per site?

Comment: no, i don't want an object containing all variables, i want different vars. if it is not possible and i have to, then one object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can pass any value, link etc to other methods:

```
import scrapy

class GotoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'goto'
    allowed_domains = ['first.com', 'second.com']
    start_urls = ['http://first.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        name = response.xpath(...)
        link = response.xpath(...)  # link for second.com where you may find the price
        request = scrapy.Request(url=link, callback = self.parse_check)
        request.meta['name'] = name
        yield request

    def parse_check(self, response):
        name = response.meta['name']
        price = response.xpath(...)
        yield {"name":name,"price":price} #Assuming that in your "items.py" the fields are declared as name, price
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. finally a good simple answer! i was looking through others stackoverflow questions and just didn't manage to understand it. but now its crystal clear. thank you!

Comment: btw your solution was passing a value to the function, how would i go about the other way around? instead of sending the name, receiving the price.