# scrapy how to yield from miltiable sources

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

a few days ago I asked this: [scrapy getting values from multiple sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258343/scrapy-getting-values-from-multiple-sites)

and I've learned how to pass value from website1 to website2. this lets my yield info from both sites, this does not solve when I have like 10 different site.

I can keep passing values from function to function but it seems idiotic. The more efficient way would be receiving the info to the parse function and yield it from there. 
here is a pseudo code of what I want to achieve.

```
import scrapy

class GotoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'goto'
    allowed_domains = ['first.com', 'second.com', 'third.com']
    start_urls = ['http://first.com/']

def parse(self, response):
    name = response.xpath(...)
    price1 = scrapy.Request(second.com, callback = self.parse_check)
    price2 = scrapy.Request(third.com, callback = self.parse_check2)
    yield(name, price1, price2)


def parse_check(self, response):
    price = response.xpath(...)
    return price

def parse_check(self, response):
    price = response.xpath(...)
    return price
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`scrapy-inline-requests`](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests), it's probably what you are looking for. Your example would then become something like:

```
import scrapy
from inline_requests import inline_requests

class GotoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'goto'
    allowed_domains = ['first.com', 'second.com', 'third.com']
    start_urls = ['http://first.com/']

    @inline_requests
    def parse(self, response):
        name = response.xpath(...)

        response1 = yield scrapy.Request(second.com)
        price1 = response1.xpath(...)
        response2 = yield scrapy.Request(third.com)
        price2 = response2.xpath(...)

        yield dict(name, price1, price2)
```

Comment: hmm seems easy enough. but why it's not a built in function? i would think it's a common idea to scrape a few sites and compare prices on the go.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there were some discussions on Github about integrating it into Scrapy, but don't remember the details. This is more of a question for developers.